# Convert Node Set Values to String

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert a node set of values to a string so that I can use the XSLT contains function. The example below fails to return 'true' and errors out because contains() doesn't handle the node set of $allColors, which should contain 'red white blue'. Does anyone know how I can convert $allColors so that it can be used in the contains method?

```
<colors>
    <color type="rgb">red</color>
    <color type="rgb">white</color>
    <color type="rgb">blue</color>
</colors>

<xsl:for-each-group select="colors/color" group-by="@type">
     <xsl:variable name="allColors" select="current-group()/color"/>
     <allColors><xsl:value-of select="contains($allColors, 'red')"/></allColors>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use contains() to test a node set? Do you want a positive answer if one of the nodes contains "reddish" or "colored"?

Comment: As the `for-each-group` groups `color` elements, your variable with `current-group()/color` selects an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with michaels comment, you can use the following though, it should get you what you want, and correctly group:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="colors/color" group-by="@type">
    <group>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="@type" /></type>
        <hasRed><xsl:value-of select="current-group() = 'red'" /></hasRed>
    </group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's responses. How I ended up searching if a specific color exists is if 
string-length(current-group()[color='red']/color) > 0.

Comment: Right. Why make it simple, when it can be complicated?